# Android: Help creating a button that produces the same result as hitting the down key on the D-Pad? (part 2)

Tags: android, keyevent

Why doesn't this work?? I am trying to create an onClickListener for a button that produces the same effect as pressing the "down" key on the D-pad. Eclipse gives me an error, saying: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sendDownUpKeyEvents(int) from the type InputMethodService" Help!

```
downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                InputMethodService.sendDownUpKeyEvents(0x00000014);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to invoke non-static method in a static way. You need to obtain an instance of the service first and then invoke the method on the instance. Also the way you're doing the simulation of keypress looks incorrect.
UPD:
After some digging I've managed to simulate key event, try:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {         
    @Override
    public void run() {                 
        new Instrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN);
    }   
}).start();
```

Comment: please forgive my stupidity but i do not fully understand what that means... how should it be written??

Comment: See the update, I'm not sure if that will work for you, but at least eclipse will not complain.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.... using your code causes a fc when the button is pressed.

logcat:
E/AndroidRuntime(  487): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught e
xception
E/AndroidRuntime(  487): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.inputmethod.
InputMethodManager
E/AndroidRuntime(  487):        at com.soapbox.servicerec.NoteEdit$2.onClick(Not
eEdit.java:520)

Any Ideas?

Comment: Post more of your stacktrace in your question

Comment: Actually scratch that.. the system service is not a InputMethodService instance. Here is good tutorial on how to simulate key presses http://www.anddev.org/throwing-simulating_keystrokes_programatically-t717.html

Comment: eclipse doesn't like some of the imports in that tutorial... i believe it is outdated.

Answer (score 3):

Same solution, just will take a parameter.

```
private void InjectKeys(final int keyEventCode) {
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   new Instrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(keyEventCode);
  }
 }).start();
}
```

Just call and pass the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE` like so `InjectKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN);`

My answer is [based on this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3526390), I just modified it to use parameters.