# Setting focus programatically in ExpandableListView. Emulating D-pad clicks in code?

Tags: android, focus, expandablelistview

I have subclassed ExpandableListActivity to create an activity that
presents a simple tree view of the 'world at large' and allows the
user to select one for further use by the app. I am having trouble
setting focus programatically. One thing that baffles me is that I can
use the D-pad to set focus on any of the child or group items in my
ExpandableListView, but inside my onChildClick() callback,
isFocusable() returns false. If I can set focus with the D-pad, how
can isFocusable() return false?

My goal is to avoid having the user have to touch individual
ExpandableListView entries to select them and to provide a couple of
buttons to move the focus up and down inside the list. I  want
selection to be easy for  folks with no D-pad or with a phone that
only presents the D-pad when in landscape mode (e.g. Droid) .

Is there some way I can programatically inject D-pad key clicks into
my app input event stream?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's good idea to simulate D-Pad keystrokes in regular app, but if you really need that, see [Android: Help creating a button that produces the same result as hitting the down key on the D-Pad? (part 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526339/android-help-creating-a-button-that-produces-the-same-result-as-hitting-the-down/3526390#3526390)

Comment: Konstantin - I wondering what you think about the default Android listview focus and selection behavior. If you don't have a d-pad, I don't know of any way to navigate the list without using the other hand to touch the screen. I want this Activity to be easy to operate with only one hand in portrait orientation (i.e. Droid d-pad would be unavailable).

The Contacts application has this same issue IMHO, you have to use the other hand to scroll and select unless you've got a d-pad available to you. Seems far from ideal ...